# vb.net Outlook 2007 error in creating new instance (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-interop

Im building an windows-form-application which will do some automation using Outlook Interop (its not a vsto addin). And this is working fine with all version except outlook 2007 which generating an error message when initiating `Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application` (Error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` ) But just after throwing the error it starts the process outlook.exe by itself, however its not performing any tasks onward.

Note: the app will only work when no outlook instance is running, so this shouldn't have any conflict with creating new instance `New Outlook.Application`. Im using visual studio 2017.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop '(Version 14.0)

Public Sub Form_Startup() Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsProcessRunning("OUTLOOK") Then
        DoSomething()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething()
  Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
  Dim oNspace As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Dim oStores As Outlook.Stores = oApp.Session.Stores
  Dim dFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  'Some code here
  'Some other code here
  Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp)
  Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oApp)
  oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

On the other hand I've also tested this `DoSomething()` part in a vsto addin which works fine in all version including 2007 without error.

## Update:

Using the following advises from fellow experts still not solving my issues in outlook 2007. I've followed the late binding along with direct version referencing to outlook 2007 as advised by @aduguid didn't solved the error message. Maybe Im miss understanding the feedback getting from the comments here.

```
Dim outlook As Object = Nothing 
outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application.12")
```

[image]

The main goal of this is to build an automation app for outlook which will work on all outlook version (e.g 2007,10,13,16), My above code is working fine with all upper version except 2007. I had to test in all office version separately for which im using separate VM while my development environment is setup with Visual Studion 2017.

Comment: Sounds like it has to do with the Outlook dll reference in your solution. I'd use late binding to get around it.

Comment: It would be great if you elaborate a little, I'm very new in vb.net

Comment: @aduguid No problem, Take your time :)

Comment: Are you sure the error is on line `Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application`? You can place breakpoints to stop code and then you can hover the mouse over the variable to see if it is in fact _Nothing_. Have a look into debugging as this will be a skill you'll need to develop. Also turn on _Option Strict_. Again you can Google how to do this etc as there isn't enough room in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of late binding with the specific version of Outlook.

```
 Dim outlook As Object = Nothing
 outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application.12")
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, I've tried the line by line debug and this time `Dim outlook As Object = Nothing` was passed, but got the error when initiating `outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

Comment: You'll need to remove the reference to the Outlook dll in your project or you can continue to use the same code you posted, but you'll need to reference the Outlook 2007 dll in your solution.

Comment: Here's an article that details your issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/242375

Comment: I've added this `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.12.0 dll` using Nuget and added this `<GuidAttribute("00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")>Public Interface Application Inherits _Application, ApplicationEvents_11_Event End Interface Dim oInst As _Application` In my code but still its giving the same error in outlook 2007

Comment: again its same, This is my [code](https://prnt.sc/ie1a3f)  and this is the error [message](https://prnt.sc/ie19n9) , here you can see, msgbx-1 is passing and then getting the error when initiating this `oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application.12")` and then eventually outlook runs , However version referencing directly in code is giving error in other version of offices e.g office 2016.